# React-native not applying styles

Tags: react-native

Styles not applying from `require`. Here is sample app, describing the problem: https://github.com/alexshk/react-native-style

Versions:

```
➜  stylestest git:(master) npm version
{ stylestest: '0.0.1',
  npm: '3.8.6',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '48',
  node: '6.1.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2h',
  uv: '1.9.0',
  v8: '5.0.71.35',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using ES5 require with ES6 export syntax, you should either change

```
var styles = require('./styles')
```

to

```
import style from ./styles'
```

or change

```
export default StyleSheet.create(...)
```

to

```
module.exports = StyleSheet.create(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it myself:

I was using `export default StyleSheet.create({` instead of `module.exports = StyleSheet.create({`